# Trying to pass different variables through onclick function () brackets

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to pass a few different cases through a function

`<div id="button1" class="button" onclick="pop(case1)">popup a</div>`

and then i want to create different cases in my function

```
function pop(a){
    if (a='case1') {var mytext = "you pressed the popup case1"; var myclass=a;}
    else if (a='case2'){var mytext = "you pressed the popup case2"; var myclass=a;}
    else if (a='case3'){var mytext = "you pressed the popup case3"; var myclass=a;}

var p1 = document.createElement("div");
    p1.classname =myclass;
    p1.innerHTML=mytext;
    document.body.appendChild(p1);
}
```

here is a fiddle i made for it 
http://jsfiddle.net/alexnode/WqsNJ/1/
How should i create the conditional if else properly? Currently i get always case1 popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are assigning with `=` rather than checking with `==`, change your `=`'s to `==`'s.

http://jsfiddle.net/WqsNJ/2/

```
if (a=='case1') {var mytext = "you pressed the popup case1"; var myclass=a;}
else if (a=='case2'){var mytext = "you pressed the popup case2"; var myclass=a;}
else if (a=='case3'){var mytext = "you pressed the popup case3"; var myclass=a;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the worst was that i had read that before!

Comment: No problem. Also, I would avoid using onclicks within the DOM. You can create listeners in the javascript itself. If using jquery, you could do something like `$(".button").on("click", function() { ... })`, and within that (`...`), you can get data from the `.class` that was actually clicked on with `this`. See [jQuery.on() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if that interests you.

Comment: I will give it a go, it seems more tidy. Is there any other reason it's not good.

Comment: Should separate your logic from your markup, it will make it easier to keep track of things or make changes in the future.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WqsNJ/3/) is an example of your code using jQuery. I noticed one thing about your code though. Tt's creating a new div every time you click, so you can end up with many duplicates of the same div in a fixed position. If you want to avoid that, check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WqsNJ/4/)

Comment: I run this whole thing through another function i call runOnce jsfiddle.net/alexnode/UD6fk/39.Your code is much more handy though!I already started to have problems with my code the more complicated it become. It might be a good idea to write it in jquerry

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare strings in JavaScript, you need to use the is **equal to operator (`==`)** instead of the **equals sign (`=`)**.

So the correct code should be

```
function pop(a){
    if (a=='case1') {var mytext = "you pressed the popup case1"; var myclass=a;}
    else if (a=='case2'){var mytext = "you pressed the popup case2"; var myclass=a;}
    else if (a=='case3'){var mytext = "you pressed the popup case3"; var myclass=a;}

var p1 = document.createElement("div");
    p1.classname =myclass;
    p1.innerHTML=mytext;
    document.body.appendChild(p1);
}
```